# Litecoin transaction history

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain

I have a litecoin wallet address. I want to know all the transactions happened for this wallet, is there any API which provides all the historical transactions related to a LTC wallet address ? Any fast response will be really helpful.

Comment: wallet addresses change, its part of the ltc (and btc) protocol for anonymising. I presume this is why question was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need an API but here's a [link](https://live.blockcypher.com/ltc/) to histories for particular address

Comment: I have a website, where I need to show all the historical transactions from any licecoin wallet address. So, if I get an API, that will suffice the purpose.

Comment: Ok so maybe checkout [this](http://explorer.litecoin.net/q) and [this](https://chain.so/api)

Comment: this will only give you history up to point your wallet created that address. Any new txs on new addresses due to anonymising part of protocol will be left out.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create your own service. This way you can get latest transactions, even when new addresses created if you use a wallet you control. So run `litecoind`, create wallet and expose an API. Litecoin should sync fairly quickly also.

I used the repo at https://github.com/uphold/docker-litecoin-core to run `litecoind` as docker container. Once containerised then you can run LTC RPC-API calls:

```
docker-compose exec litecoind litcoin-cli --help
```